# Hit metal piece while drilling through condo concrete ceiling

Tags: electrical, concrete, light-fixture, drill, wire

I am trying to install wide rectangular light fixture.

Something similar to this:
https://www.amazon.ca/Feit-Rectangle-Ceiling-Lighting-Diffused/dp/B00Y86OROW

I Hit a metal piece while drilling through condo concrete ceiling.
Is this dangerous?
Did I hit a wire?
The screw is quite long. How do I recover from this?

[image: ceiling holes]
[image: metal piece]

Comment: it's possible that you found the conduit going to that junction box , if you didn't drill through it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a piece of rebar, usually plumbing and wiring in a multistory building will be in a electrical / plumbing chase, not in the “floor / ceiling”.  No recovery needed, I would get a shorter concrete screw it looks like you have a fairly deep hole. Those led panels are not much of a load and you should have at least 2 screws if not 4 so cut that screw down or get a shorter one.

Comment: 1 1/4" Tapcons, four of them.